# Content change on hook

Tags: 7, hooks, wysiwyg

I am working on a new content type. I created a hook that loops through a .csv file on its load, and makes a table from it.

What I want to do now is including this new table automatically in the CKEditor field, in the same form.

How can I do this? You don't have to tell me exactly what to do. Just some hints on which function to use would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hook YOUR_MODULE_form_CONTENT_TYPE_node_form_alter() fill the field (that outputs in the  ckeditor) with your HTML, like:

```
$form['field_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $your_html;
```

You also need to make sure, that the  tags get saved, by adding these tags to allowed ones for your ckeditor!